# Trouble with classes

Tags: c#, oop, class

I know classes aren't used much in VB.NET. I have looked everywhere trying to understand how classes work in C#, it's as if I needed an analogy for each lesson I have learned, I have logic and loops down, but when it comes to classes, my brain just freezes up. I have tried books and online tutorials. I for the life of me cannot understand how classes work and how they are called between linking. Its almost as hard for me to learn pointers in C.

Does anyone know a good resource or site that will break it down evenly even for the non-gifted tech?

Comment: `I know classes aren't used much in VB.NET.` ehh? Most things in VB.NET are classes.

Comment: Of course classes are used in VB.NET - whatever makes you think they're not?

Comment: So you're basically asking to explain what classes are and how they work in C#?

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of resources all over the internet with this information, no doubt, but if I may point out what is noted in the [C# Language Specification](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=c#%20specification&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CC8QFjAB&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/8/388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09/csharp%2520language%2520specification.doc&ei=BF2lTvXIHYXRhAeF9oHMBA&usg=AFQjCNGXik09_Rn-k0FGHG-A6v1EX3RLyA&sig2=5U5aR1hsLJKQwahXsjUhpw) (with further linkage):

> **1.6 Classes and objects**
>
> [***Classes***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b0thckt.aspx) are the most fundamental of C#’s types. A class is a data structure that combines state (fields) and
>   actions (methods and other function members) in a single unit. A class
>   provides a definition for dynamically created [***instances***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) of the class,
>   also known as [***objects***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173110.aspx). Classes support [***inheritance***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and [***polymorphism***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152%28v=VS.100%29.aspx),
>   mechanisms whereby [***derived classes***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228387%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) can extend and specialize ***base
>   classes***.
>
> New classes are created using class declarations. A class
>   declaration starts with a header that specifies the attributes and
>   modifiers of the class, the name of the class, the base class (if
>   given), and the [interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) implemented by the class. The header is
>   followed by the class body, which consists of a list of member
>   declarations written between the delimiters { and }.
>
> The following is a declaration of a simple class named Point:

```
public class Point
{
    public int x, y;
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

> Instances of classes are created using the new operator, which
>   allocates memory for a new instance, invokes a constructor to
>   initialize the instance, and returns a reference to the instance. The
>   following statements create two Point objects and store references to
>   those objects in two variables:

```
Point p1 = new Point(0, 0); 
Point p2 = new Point(10, 20);
```

> The memory occupied by an object is [automatically
>   reclaimed when the object is no longer in use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx). It is neither necessary
>   nor possible to explicitly deallocate objects in C#.

This information is the bottom line, and should be *coldly understood* - the links to important peripheral (but fundamental) aspects go some way to provide further reading. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

A class:

```
public class Program
{
    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
    }
}
```

running it:

```
var program = new Program();
program.Run();
```